# The update only happens in the 1st database and not with the 2nd

Tags: php, mysql

When we try to update, all the outputs ("Successful step") 1,2,4,5 are shown. But when we try to check the database, only the 1st database was able to do the update.

```
$host = "172.16.1.16";
$user  = "root";
$password =  "root";
$dbname1 = "nocs";
$dbname2 = "nocs_backup";
```

Here is the first database

```
$db1 = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname1);
if($db1->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database' . $db1->connect_error);
}
else
{
    $updateComponentSql = "UPDATE component 
                           SET `Component_name`='$name', `Brand`='$brand', 
                               `Model`='$model', `Type`='$type',
                               `Capacity`='$capacity',`Serial_no`='$serial', 
                               `Description`='Installed' 
                           WHERE `Component_id`='$d_id' 
                           AND `computer_id`='$c_id'";

    if (mysqli_query($db1, $updateComponentSql))
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                alert('Succesful step 1');
              </script>";   
    }
```

Here is the second

```
    $db2 = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname2);
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Succesful step 2');</script>";

    if($db2->connect_errno > 0)
    {   
        die('Unable to connect to database' . $db2->connect_error);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successful step 3');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Succesful step 4');</script>";
            if (mysqli_query($db2, "UPDATE component 
                                    SET (`Component_name`='$name', 
                                         `Brand`='$brand', `Model`='$model', 
                                         `Type`='$type',`Capacity`='$capacity',
                                         `Serial_no`='$serial', 
                                         `Description`='Installed' 
                                     WHERE `Component_id`='$d_id' 
                                     AND `computer_id`='$c_id)" ))
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                        alert('Succesful step 5');
                      </script>";
            }   
        }

}
```

We're at our wit's end. Please help us :(

Comment: Your second `UPDATE` has a syntax error. Get rid of the parentheses.

Comment: check `mysqli_affected_rows($db2)` maybe there simply was no matching record. Also print the actual query somewhere (to the browser if yo must, to a log file preferably), maybe the parameters are different from  what you expect. see also: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: btw: `all the outputs ("Successful step") 1,2,4,5 are shown` - you are sure that the step 5 alert is shown? Because as pointed out there _is_ an error in your query and mysqli_query() shold never return true on this one.

Comment: @VolkerK yes. The step 5 notification is being shown although there is no change in the second database. It really baffles me as well as to why it would perform the echo part. Is there any way we could know what the      if statement     returned?

Comment: You might want to install a debugger, https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

You have extraneous parentheses in the second `UPDATE` query.

```
if (mysqli_query($db2, "UPDATE component 
                        SET `Component_name`='$name', `Brand`='$brand', `Model`='$model', 
                            `Type`='$type', `Capacity`='$capacity', `Serial_no`='$serial', 
                            `Description`='Installed' 
                        WHERE `Component_id`='$d_id' AND `computer_id`='$c_id" ))
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Succesful step 5');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(" . json_encode(mysqli_error($db2)) . ");</script>";
}
```